# Input validation to only accept numbers

Tags: c++, validation, c++11

I'm creating  program and it should only be allowed to accept numbers if a letter is entered it should re-ask the use to enter a number. When i run the code i get an error saying there's a problem with the break heres a copy of my code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Triangle
{
    private:
        double base;
        double height;
    public:
        void setBase(double);
        void setHeight(double);
        double getBase() const;
        double getHeight() const;
        double getArea() const;
};

void Triangle::setBase(double b)
{
    base = b;
}

void Triangle::setHeight(double hg)
{
    height = hg;
}

double Triangle::getBase() const
{
    return base;
}

ouble Triangle::getHeight() const
{
    return height;
}

double Triangle::getArea() const
{
    return .50 *(base * height);
}

int main()
{
    double number; 
    double totalArea;
    Triangle one; 
    Triangle two;
    Triangle three;

    do
    {
        cout << "What is the base of Triangle One:"; 
        cin >> number;

        one.setBase(number); 
            cout << "You have entered " << number << " for the base of the triangle.\n";

        cout << "What is the height of Triangle One:"; 
        cin >> number;
        one.setHeight(number); 
            cout << "You have entered " << number << " for the height of the triangle.\n";

            cout << "What is the base of Triangle Two: "; 
        cin >> number;
        two.setBase(number); 
            cout << "You have entered " << number << " for the base of the triangle.\n";

        cout << "What is the height of Triangle Two:"; 
        cin >> number;
        two.setHeight(number); 
            cout << "You have entered " << number << " for the height of the triangle.\n";

            cout << "What is the base of Triangle Three:"; 
        cin >> number;
        three.setBase(number); 
            cout << "You have entered " << number << " for the base of the triangle.\n";

        cout << "What is the height of Triangle Three:"; 
        cin >> number;
        three.setHeight(number); 
             cout << "You have entered " << number << " for the height of the triangle.\n";
    }   
    while (0); 
    {
        if (cin >> number) 
        {
            break;
        } 
        else 
        {
            cout << "Invalid Input! Please input a numerical value." << endl;
                    cin.clear();
            while (cin.get() != '\n') ; 
        }
    }


    totalArea = one.getArea() + two.getArea() + three.getArea(); 

    cout << "The total area of the three triangles is " << totalArea << endl; 

    return 0; 

}
```

Here's the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3GhJ.png) im receiving

Comment: Show the **exact error message**.

Comment: `while (0);` is not right. Drop the `;`.

Comment: Also `0` is considered to be `false`, so this loop will never be entered (even once you fix the `;`).

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi I've added the error message

Comment: @WhozCraig ive changed the 0 to 1 and dropped the ; and i'm still receiving same error

Comment: @BoBTFish  ive changed the 0 to 1 and dropped the ; and i'm still receiving same error

Comment: Pfft. Duh. Sorry, Now that I look closer, it's because you have a `do {...} while(0); {.... break... }`. The ensuing `break` has no loop or switch, therefore nothing to break. What are you trying to `break` from? This almost looks like the code *after* the do-while is intended to be used for each read of `number` above, but that isn't how the language works.

Comment: @WhozCraig ok i removed the do while loope and moved the if else loop after the first cout statement its working, but im trying to loop it to where it will do it for ever input its asks for and if its invalid it asks the user to re-enter the input

Comment: I understand. That code in the `{ }` following the loop looks like it should be its own function (or lambda), and invoked in each of the numeric entry points within your do-while. I'll draw up an answer for your unless someone else does it first.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the d in double on:

```
ouble Triangle::getHeight() const
{
    return height;
}
```

Comment: Observant, but has *nothing* to do with the question.

Comment: sorry its just how the code was input on here but i have the d

Comment: @WhozCraig It does have to do with the question. The main goal of the poster is to not receive errors in their program.

Answer (score 0):

**do while** syntax should be like this:

```
do{

}while(x == 0);
```

How you did it is like this:

```
do{

}while();
{ <--- //this

} <--- //and this
```

Try removing those two parentheses {}. They are not necessary.

Comment: While correct, this will not correct the problem of a `break` with no loop or switch to attach to.

Answer (score 0):

1. do{
   ...
   }while(0);

means your loop is done exactly once. It will exit always. So you can spare this do-while loop.

2. The code after while(0); looks like a function which is supposed to test the user input.

I would introduce strings and exceptions and write it like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//Work-Class 
class Triangle {
private:
    double base;
    double height;

public:
    void setBase(double);
    void setHeight(double);
    double getBase() const;
    double getHeight() const;
    double getArea() const;
};

void Triangle::setBase(double b) {
    base = b;
}

void Triangle::setHeight(double hg) {
    height = hg;
}

double Triangle::getBase()const {
    return base;
}

double Triangle::getHeight() const {
    return height;
}

double Triangle::getArea() const {
    return (base*height) / 2;
}

//conversion and test function
double getDoubleString(string questString) {
    string userAnswer;
    double d;

    cout << questString;
    getline(cin, userAnswer);
    try {
        d = stod(userAnswer);
    }
    catch (const std::invalid_argument& ia) {
        cerr << "Invalid argument: " << ia.what() << '\n';
        d = 0.0;
    }
    return d;
}

//Enter the hell
int main() {
    double number;
    double totalArea;
    Triangle one;
    Triangle two;
    Triangle three;

    cout << "--------------------------------------------------------------\n\n";
    //Triangle one
    one.setBase(getDoubleString("What is the base of Triangle One: "));
    cout << "You have entered " << one.getBase() << " for the base of the triangle.\n";
    one.setHeight(getDoubleString("What is the height of Triangle One: "));
    cout << "You have entered " << one.getHeight() << " for the height of the triangle.\n\n";

    //Triangle two
    two.setBase(getDoubleString("What is the base of Triangle Two: "));
    cout << "You have entered " << two.getBase() << " for the base of the triangle.\n";
    two.setHeight(getDoubleString("What is the height of Triangle Two: "));
    cout << "You have entered " << two.getHeight() << " for the height of the triangle.\n\n";

    //Triangle three
    three.setBase(getDoubleString("What is the base of Triangle Three: "));
    cout << "You have entered " << three.getBase() << " for the base of the triangle.\n";
    three.setHeight(getDoubleString("What is the height of Triangle Three: "));
    cout << "You have entered " << three.getHeight() << " for the height of the triangle.\n\n";

    totalArea = one.getArea() + two.getArea() + three.getArea();

    cout << "--------------------------------------------------------------\n\n";
    cout << "The total area of the three triangles ist " << totalArea << endl;
    return 0;
}
```